# How to validate properly in EF WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-web-api

I have a model of Projects and Time spent within those projects, that uses DTOs with a Web API front end. I'm trying to work out how to do the validation properly.

Most of my validation is on the attributes of the DTO classes, such as (for the `TimeDTO`):

```
[Required, MinLength(3), MaxLength(50)]
public string Description { get; set; }

[Required]
public short Minutes { get; set; }

//...
```

However, I also need to validate that the date on the `Time` instance is within the `StartDate` & `EndDate` on the associated `Project` instance.

To do this I would need to lookup the `Project` in the `DbContext` from the `ProjectId` field on the `TimeDTO` instance.

So if one option is to make the `TimeDTO` an `IValidatableObject`, then I need to new up a `DbContext` in the model, which doesn't seem right to me.

The other option is to validate it in the Controller but since then I have validation in the model AND the controller, so I'm not sure about that...

Any suggestions on how to do this more "correctly"?

Comment: Did you turn loading of navigation properties off? If not, you can simply access the associated project

Comment: I didn't turn it off (as far as I am aware!) - but this is a DTO object, not the object retrieved from the database, so the navigation properties are not populated.

Comment: Have you tried EagerLoading the properties you need with an `Include` statement?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see that as appropriate. Say I'm inserting a new Time record: the TimeDTO comes from the UI, not from the database, so the TimeDTO instance can't load the Project (it's null), I'd have to manually load it by doing `DbContext.Projects.Find(timeDTO.ProjectId)`. But as I've said, that requires accessing the DbContext in the Model. It seems more appropriate to validate this in the Controller where the DbContext is initialised.

Comment: The default fluent validation through properties can only validate your dto so much. Because you need to access the database to do validation, you have to either validate the dto in your controller or write a custom IModelBinder, IValueProvider or HttpParameterBinding.
(Id go with 2nd line validation in the controller)

Comment: @Dietz That's what I'm getting at, I guess - is it ok to have validation in the controller? I've read that it's not, and put all validation in the model, but this seems like a good argument to have (some of) the validation in the controller.

Comment: @Sean I think the validation you can put into the model are limited to validating that the Date is indeed a date (read: not null, empty string and follows some sort of meaningful format... the usual). Validation of constraints imposed by related data in your database seems like a whole other kind of validation. That is why id put it into the controller.

Comment: Ok, I'd be happy to mark that as an answer if it were one. Thanks.